# How to return a codepoint as char representation in Elixir maps?

Tags: elixir

`Map.new([?A, ?B], fn n -> {n, count('ABB', n)} end)`

(`count` is essentially Enum.count/2) returns an error:

`(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{65 => 0, 66 => 2} of type Map.`

How do I transform the keys to this representation:

`%{?A => 1, ?B => 2}`

Answer (score 2):

> `%{65 => 0, 66 => 2}` [...]
>   How do I transform the keys to this representation:
>   `%{?A => 1, ?B => 2}`

These two representations are essentially the same. `?A` is the syntactic sugar to *input* ordinal values of ASCII symbols, there is no way to make it to output integers that way.

```rb
iex(1)> ?A == 65
#⇒ true
```

`IO.inspect/2` perfectly outputs the result:

```rb
Map.new([?A, ?B], fn n ->
  {n, Enum.count('ABB', & &1 == n)}
end)
#⇒ %{65 => 1, 66 => 2}
```

The issue you have is somewhere you attempt to `IO.puts(map)` and, unlike `IO.inspect/2`, `IO.puts/1` requires the argument to implement `String.Chars` protocol.

Get rid of this `IO.puts/1` call, or change it to `IO.inspect/2` call, and you are all set.

---

*Sidenote:* you might get `A` back that way:

```rb
IO.puts [65]
#⇒ A
```

Answer (score 0):

`<<66 :: utf8>>`
converts the codepoint `66` in to a `B`

see here
https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html

Comment: or `List.to_string([66])` also returns `B`

Comment: *How to return a codepoint as char representation...?* --  Perfectly answers the title question.

Answer (score -1):

```
iex(5)> %{?A => 1, ?B => 2}
%{65 => 1, 66 => 2}
```

> How do I transform the keys to this representation:
>
> ```
> %{?A => 1, ?B => 2}
> ```

That's like asking, how do I get the following map

```
%{
   fn(x) -> x+2 end.(4) => "hello", 
   fn(x) -> x-2 end.(10) => "goodbye"
}
```

to display as:

```
%{
   fn(x) -> x+2 end.(63) => "hello", 
   fn(x) -> x-2 end.(68) => "goodbye"
}
```

The answer is: you can't.  The reason is: because `fn(x) -> x+2 end.(63)` is a syntax that tells elixir to replace the function call with the return value of the function.  So, the map is actually:

```
%{65 => "hello", 66 => "goodbye"}
```

There's no way to convert the key `65` to the function call `fn(x) -> x+2 end.(63)`.  Similarly, the syntax `?A` tells elixir to replace that syntax with the ascii code for the character `A`, i.e. 65, and there's no way to convert 65 to the syntax `?A`.

If you actually want strings such as `"?A"` and `"?B"` as the keys, then you can do this:

```
defmodule B do
  def go(list, char_codes) do
    for key <- list, into: %{} do
      val = Enum.count(char_codes, fn(code) -> key==code end)
      {"?#{<<key>>}", val}
    end
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex b.ex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

warning: redefining module B (current version loaded from Elixir.B.beam)
  b.ex:1

Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> B.go([?A, ?B], 'ABB')
%{"?A" => 1, "?B" => 2}
```

And, if you just want the strings `"A"` and `"B"` as the keys, then the code becomes:

```
defmodule B do
  def go(list, char_codes) do
    for key <- list, into: %{} do
      val = Enum.count(char_codes, fn(code) -> key==code end)
      {<<key>>, val}
    end
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(1)> B.go([?A, ?B], 'ABB')                    
%{"A" => 1, "B" => 2}
```